# java -cp brings up help options?

Tags: java, command-prompt

So, I'm trying to run a compiled class file in command prompt on windows 8 like this-

> java -cp C:\Java\MyFirstProgram

However, every time I run it using the -cp option, it brings up a list of several help options, such as defining -cp, -showversion, -X, -splash, etc. I've tried several other ways of typing it as well, however when I don't use the -cp option, it says

> Error: Could not find or load main class C:\Java\MyFirstProgram

Other questions on Stack mentioned how I should be using -cp, so I tried that and only the help showed up, which was very.. Unhelpful. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? And if so, thanks for responding if you do.

Edit: This is the source code

```
public class MyFirstProgram
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

So how would I include the "class file," then?

Comment: What arguments does the [`java` command](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) take?

Comment: You need to specify which class you want to run: `java -cp C:\Java\MyFirstProgram mypackage.MyClass`

Comment: You did not specify a class to run.

Comment: `-cp` sets the class path. Just use `java MyFirstProgram`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct usage of using `java` executable is:

```
java [-options] class [args...]
```

where `-options` include the `-cp` command option.

You haven't included your class file, therefore it displays to you the usage help.

---

To run your program, go to your Java folder and run your program.

Example:

```
cd C:\Java
java MyFirstProgram
```

Comment: How would I include the class file? Judging from the comment above, it seems like I would need to say
`java C:\Java\MyFirstProgram (Class File)`
However I don't understand what the class file refers to.

Comment: @Aetharius, every java file is compiled to a class file (with a `.class` extension). You will need to specify with class file to execute and that class file is the java file that contains the `main` method. E.g.: `java -cp C:\Java\MyFirstProgram MyMainClass` where `MyMainClass` is the class file that contains the `main` method.

Comment: Ah, I see. So I adjusted it to be like 
`java -cp C:\Java\MyFirstProgram MyFirstProgram` since that is the class that contains the main method. However, now when I run that instead of bringing up the help, it says
`Error: Could not find or load main class MyFirstProgram`
Instead of saying
`Error: Could not find or load main class C:\Java\MyFirstProgram` Although it makes sense and seems to have improved it, the result is still the same.

Answer (score -2):

I'm guessing the problem is that you need to specify the .class extension:

```
java -cp C:\Java\MyFirstProgram.class
```

Comment: Not quite: `-cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>`